# Communication Between Asp.net MVC and window Store app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-store-apps

Please let me know the procedure for communication between window store app and MVC such that data can be passed from MVC to Store app and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean call to a web API?

You can use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to send http requests & receive responses.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

A detailed guide available [Here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/consuming-asp-net-web-api-services-in-a-windows-8-c-xaml-app/). It shows how you can use WebApi with Windows store app.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to connect to a web service is to use the [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) (which supersedes System.Net.Http.HttpClient). This can be used to send any normal HTTP request (PUT, POST, GET, etc.)

```
using Windows.Web.Http;   

using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/27796508?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow");

    try
    {
        string json = await hc.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle network exceptions
    }
}
```

See [How to connect to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx) on MSDN and the [HttpClient sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=242550) for more details.